# Discord Python Bot - Trying to track time spent in a VC

Tags: python, list, discord, discord.py

I want to track the time spent in vc by users but after a while of checking, we see that their time has reduced which makes no sense. I want to check 3 channels every minute for which members are inside those channels and in the member_info list, increase the time stored in member_info[member_index][1] if they are in one of the 3 channels. I can't understand why the total time is reducing if I only add values to the list and if the file is only read to initialise the list.

```
member_info = []
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents = intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("We have logged in as {0.user}".format(bot))
    global member_info
    f = open("times.txt")
    content = f.readlines()
    for i in range (0, len(content)):
        content[i] = content[i].split(", ")
        content[i][0] = int(content[i][0])
        content[i][1] = int(content[i][1].strip())
        member_info.append(content[i])
    print(member_info)
    track_user_time.start()
    update_file.start()

@bot.command()
async def myTime(ctx):
    author = ctx.author.id
    global member_info
    for b in range (0, len(member_info)):
        if (member_info[b][0] == author):
            time_spent = member_info[b][1]
            user_days = time_spent // 3600
            user_hours = (time_spent - (user_days*3600)) // 60
            user_minutes = time_spent - (user_days*3600) - (user_hours *60) 
            time_msg = f"""
            Time Spent by: {ctx.author.name}
            Days Spent Studying: {user_days} day(s)
            Hours Spent Studying: {user_hours} hour(s)
            Minutes Spent Studying: {user_minutes} minutes
            """
            await ctx.send(time_msg)


@tasks.loop(seconds=60)
async def track_user_time():
    global member_info 
    active_members = []
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    channel = bot.get_channel(868830478705233993)
    members = channel.members
    for k in range (0, len(members)):
        if (members[k].id not in active_members):
            active_members.append(members[k].id)
    #find their id for each work channel
    #look for corresponding id in member_info
    #add 1 minute to their time spent studying
    channel = bot.get_channel(868835241958182984)
    members = channel.members
    for p in range (0, len(members)):
        if (members[p].id not in active_members):
            active_members.append(members[p].id)

    channel = bot.get_channel(868835476147146752)
    members = channel.members
    for o in range (0, len(members)):
        if (members[o].id not in active_members):
            active_members.append(members[o].id)

    print(active_members)
    for f in range (0, len(member_info)):
        for y in range(0, len(active_members)):
            if (member_info[f][0] == active_members[y]):
                member_info[f][1] = member_info[f][1] + 1
    print("working")


@tasks.loop(seconds = 90)
async def update_file():
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    f = open('times.txt', 'w')
    for q in range(0, len(member_info)): 
        file_info = str(member_info[q][0]) + ", " + str(member_info[q][1]) + "\n"
        f.write(file_info)
    print("updated")
```

Comment: In python they're not called `arrays` but `lists`

Comment: Please consider learning how to iterate in Python what you are doing works but not recommended.